# PHP MongoDB Find out queries returning the bigger size

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a replica set with 3 nodes. Currently, each one of these nodes is sending back a lot of data (almost 1TB per day).

I plan to start using projection when performing the queries, in order to return non-used data for the process, but I have several queries, so in order to prioritize and optimize I would like to know which current queries are returning the biggest amount of data (in MB).

Is there any way I can get this data? I guess I could implement a kind of function in php that measures the retrieved data from MongoDB, but it would be ideal if somehow I can have this info from MongoDB directly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can find out from Mongodb logs.

> When MongoDB writes query profile information to the log, the responseLength value is in a field named reslen.

You need to enable [logging](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/) and [profiling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/). Then you will find `reslen` for each query which takes place. It is in bytes. You can analyse the logs and find out which one takes more size.

Sample log line:

```
2019-01-14T12:00:59.166-0500 I COMMAND  [conn4] command test.items appName: "MongoDB Shell" 
command: aggregate { aggregate: "items", pipeline: [ { $match: { a: { $lte: 500.0 } } }, 
numYields:98113 nreturned:101 queryHash:811451DD planCacheKey:759981BA **reslen:1305014**
```

It has many more parameters. I just added few relevant.